# Custom product price suffix on based on product categories in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy, price

I need to add 'per metre' to the price on most of my online catalogue, I tried the code on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50954526/custom-product-price-suffix-for-selected-product-categories-in-woocommerce) in my finctions.php but I cannot get it to omit/include particular categories- it seems to be all or nothing. What am I doing wrong?

I have edited the code as such:

```
/*add 'per metre' after selected items*/
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'conditional_price_suffix', 20, 2 );
function conditional_price_suffix( $price, $product ) {
    // HERE define your product categories (can be IDs, slugs or names)
    $product_categories = array('fabric','haberdashery', 'lining',);

    if( ! has_term( $product_categories, 'fasteners', 'patches', 'remnnants', $product->get_id() ) )
        $price .= ' ' . __('per metre');

    return $price;
}
```

I want 'fabrics', 'haberdashery', 'lining' to show per metre, and 'fasteners', 'patches', 'remnants' to NOT show the suffix.

I have tried variations of the code -my exclusions in the top bit and the inclusions in the second part, and with/without the "( ! has term" section, but whichever I do takes all the suffix messages away, or applies to all categories.

It would be amazing if I could get this to work as have previously been using a very bloated plug-in. I'm only basically capable in this stuff so please feel free to talk me through it as if I am an idiot.

Comment: There is a comment zone below my answer where you can add a comment related to my answer and I will be notified (instead of making a comment in an answer). **My code is tested and works perfectly.** Note that `has_term()` function doesn't work on parent product categories or child subcategories. You need to specify the product categories set in your related products. Now 20 is the hook priority and 2 the number of arguments (variables) in the function, and there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: This doesn't work for me and I suspect it is to do with parent/child categories, if it doesn't work on them what does it work on? My parent categories are 'Fabric', 'Haberdashery', all other categories I have are beneath them - eg 'jersey' (sold per metre) and 'buttons (sold individually).

Comment: If the `has_term ( ) ` function doesn't work on my categories is there another function that does?

Answer (score 2):

There is a little mistake in your code in the `has_term()` function.

To handle parent product categories, we will use a custom conditional function instead of `has_tem()`.

I have also added some code **to handle the product variation selected price** of variable products, So try this instead:

```
// Custom conditional function that handle parent product categories too
function has_product_categories( $categories, $product_id = 0 ) {
    $parent_term_ids = $categories_ids = array(); // Initializing
    $taxonomy        = 'product_cat';
    $product_id      = $product_id == 0 ? get_the_id() : $product_id;

    if( is_string( $categories ) ) {
        $categories = (array) $categories; // Convert string to array
    }

    // Convert categories term names and slugs to categories term ids
    foreach ( $categories as $category ){
        $result = (array) term_exists( $category, $taxonomy );
        if ( ! empty( $result ) ) {
            $categories_ids[] = reset($result);
        }
    }

    // Loop through the current product category terms to get only parent main category term
    foreach( get_the_terms( $product_id, $taxonomy ) as $term ){
        if( $term->parent > 0 ){
            $parent_term_ids[] = $term->parent; // Set the parent product category
            $parent_term_ids[] = $term->term_id; // (and the child)
        } else {
            $parent_term_ids[] = $term->term_id; // It is the Main category term and we set it.
        }
    }
    return array_intersect( $categories_ids, array_unique($parent_term_ids) ) ? true : false;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'conditional_price_suffix', 10, 2 );
function conditional_price_suffix( $price, $product ) {
    // Handling product variations
    $product_id = $product->is_type('variation') ? $product->get_parent_id() : $product->get_id();

    // HERE define your product categories (can be IDs, slugs or names)
    $product_categories = array('fabric','haberdashery', 'lining');

    if( has_product_categories( $product_categories, $product_id ) )
        $price .= ' ' . __('per metre');

    return $price;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). tested and works.

[image]

Comment: This is a great solution, thank you. How would you go about showing this in the Cart?