# Product price suffix with a price calculation based on weight in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

I am using *"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53435276/custom-product-price-suffix-on-based-on-product-categories-in-woocommerce/53438506#53438506"* answer thread that allow to adjust my pricing display with a prefix this way:

```
    $price .= ' ' . __('/ $7.50 per serving');
```

But what I would actually like is to make the `$price` output what the price of the item is divided by the weight of the item. How would I do this?

Here is my actual code lightly changed *(that uses `has_product_categories()`from [**this thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53435276/custom-product-price-suffix-on-based-on-product-categories-in-woocommerce/53438506#53438506))*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'conditional_price_suffix', 10, 2 );
function conditional_price_suffix( $price, $product ) {
    // Handling product variations
    $product_id = $product->is_type('variation') ? $product->get_parent_id() : $product->get_id();

    // HERE define your product categories (can be IDs, slugs or names)
    $product_categories = array('monthly-menus');

    if( has_product_categories( $product_categories, $product_id ) )
        $price .= ' ' . __('/ $7.50 per serving');

    return $price;
}
```

I tried a whole bunch of things that outputted `NAN` on the front end. Don't think I'm doing it right!

Answer (score 1):

The following will add your prefix with a calculated price per serving:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'conditional_price_suffix', 10, 2 );
function conditional_price_suffix( $price, $product ) {
    $weight    = (float) $product->get_weight();
    $raw_price = (float) wc_get_price_to_display($product);

    // Handling product variations
    $product_id = $product->is_type('variation') ? $product->get_parent_id() : $product->get_id();

    // HERE define your product categories (can be IDs, slugs or names)
    $product_categories = array('monthly-menus');
    $product_categories = array('clothing');

    if( has_product_categories( $product_categories, $product_id ) && $weight > 0 )
        $price .= ' ' . sprintf( __('/ %s per serving'), strip_tags( wc_price( $weight / $raw_price ) ) );
    return $price;
}
```

You will have to include `has_product_categories()` the function code from [**this thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53435276/custom-product-price-suffix-on-based-on-product-categories-in-woocommerce/53438506#53438506).

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). tested and works.