# Custom product price suffix based on product in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, suffix

I need help to be able to display a different price suffix per product. Currently I have found code that displays price suffix according to categories but it doesn’t solve the issue as I need it be different for some products in the same categories.

The *[Custom product price suffix for selected product categories in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50954526/custom-product-price-suffix-for-selected-product-categories-in-woocommerce/50954842#50954842)* answer code is based on categories. Can it be altered only for specific products instead?

Comment: you could use `in_array` based on the product ID. `$my_array = array( 1, 2, 3 ); if ( in_array( $product->get_id(), $my_array ) ) {...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case someone is wondering how this can be applied based on the already existing code.

[`in_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) - Checks if a value exists in an array

```php
function filter_woocommerce_get_price_html( $price, $product ) {
    // Set specfic product ID's
    $specific_product_ids = array( 1, 2, 3 );

    // Checks if a value exists in an array
    if ( in_array( $product->get_id(), $specific_product_ids ) ) {
        $price .= ' ' . __( 'per kg', 'woocommerce' );
    }

    return $price;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'filter_woocommerce_get_price_html', 10, 2 );
```

---

To deal with multiple suffixes, you could use [`PHP: switch`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)

```php
function filter_woocommerce_get_price_html( $price, $product ) {
    // Get product ID
    $product_id = $product->get_id();
    
    // Set product ID's kg
    $product_ids_kg = array( 30, 813, 815 );
    
    // Set product ID's g
    $product_ids_g = array( 817, 819, 821 );
    
    // Checks if a value exists in an array 
    switch ( $product_id ) {
        case in_array( $product_id, $product_ids_kg ):
            $suffix = ' per kg';
            break;
        case in_array( $product_id, $product_ids_g ):
            $suffix = ' per 500g';
            break;
        default:
            $suffix = '';
    }

    // Return
    return $price . __( $suffix, 'woocommerce' );
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'filter_woocommerce_get_price_html', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thanks for this response. I have run into an issue where I don't understand how to do multiple suffixes now. So there is one for "per kg" but how do I do another for "per 500g"? I have 10 variations. I see if i dplicate the code, that doesn't really work.

Comment: I have updated my answer for your additional question