# Exclude specific product ids from a category price suffix change in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, prefix, price

Based on [Custom product price suffix for selected product categories in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50954526/custom-product-price-suffix-for-selected-product-categories-in-woocommerce/50954842#50954842) answer code, I have used the following to change the price suffix in a specific product category to ‘per kg’. However, there are two products in this category I need to exclude from this. Could anyone tell me whether this is possible please.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'conditional_price_suffix', 20, 2 );
function conditional_price_suffix( $price, $product ) {
    // HERE define your product categories (can be IDs, slugs or names)
    $product_categories = array('cheese');

    if( has_term( $product_categories, 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) )
$price .= ' ' . __('per kg');
    
return $price;
}
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following *(where you will define the product ids to be excluded)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'conditional_price_suffix', 20, 2 );
function conditional_price_suffix( $price, $product ) {
    // HERE define your product categories (can be IDs, slugs or names)
    $product_categories = array('cheese');

    // HERE define your products Ids to be excluded
    $excluded_ids = array(37, 57);

    if( has_term( $product_categories, 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) 
    && ! in_array( $product->get_id(), $excluded_ids ) ) {
        $price .= ' ' . __('per kg');
    }
    
    return $price;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). It should works.